# WebGl - Can only draw one object

Tags: javascript, opengl, opengl-es, shader, webgl

I'm trying to write a cube function to fork off from this [example](http://learningwebgl.com/lessons/lesson04/index.html) - why does only one cube show up when I've made several calls to my makeCube() function. I have a hunch something weird is going on with when I do push/pop matrix. I'm a new to webgl and have written a game already using canvas2d and would like to break into opengl with a web browser. Help! I promise you can beta test my 1st 3d game What am I doing wrong? (my code appears below)

```
        <html> 

        <head> 
        <title>Learning WebGL &mdash; lesson 4</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> 

        <script type="text/javascript" src="glMatrix-0.9.5.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="webgl-utils.js"></script> 

        <script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment"> 
            #ifdef GL_ES
            precision highp float;
            #endif

            varying vec4 vColor;

            void main(void) {
                gl_FragColor = vColor;
            }
        </script> 

        <script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex"> 
            attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
            attribute vec4 aVertexColor;

            uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
            uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

            varying vec4 vColor;

            void main(void) {
                gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
                vColor = aVertexColor;
            }
        </script> 


        <script type="text/javascript"> 

            var gl;

            function initGL(canvas) {
                try {
                    gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
                    gl.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
                    gl.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
                } catch (e) {
                }
                if (!gl) {
                    alert("Could not initialise WebGL, sorry :-(");
                }
            }


            function getShader(gl, id) {
                var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);
                if (!shaderScript) {
                    return null;
                }

                var str = "";
                var k = shaderScript.firstChild;
                while (k) {
                    if (k.nodeType == 3) {
                        str += k.textContent;
                    }
                    k = k.nextSibling;
                }

                var shader;
                if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
                    shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
                } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
                    shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
                } else {
                    return null;
                }

                gl.shaderSource(shader, str);
                gl.compileShader(shader);

                if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
                    alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
                    return null;
                }

                return shader;
            }

            var shaderProgram;
            function initShaders() {
                var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
                var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");

                shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
                gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
                gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
                gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

                if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
                    alert("Could not initialise shaders");
                }

                gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

                shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
                gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);

                shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexColor");
                gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute);

                shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
                shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");
            }

            var mvMatrix = mat4.create();
            var mvMatrixStack = [];
            var pMatrix = mat4.create();

            function mvPushMatrix() {
                var copy = mat4.create();
                mat4.set(mvMatrix, copy);
                mvMatrixStack.push(copy);
            }

            function mvPopMatrix() {
                if (mvMatrixStack.length == 0) {
                    throw "Invalid popMatrix!";
                }
                mvMatrix = mvMatrixStack.pop();
            }

            function setMatrixUniforms() {
                gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform, false, pMatrix);
                gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform, false, mvMatrix);
            }


            function degToRad(degrees) {
                return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
            }


            var pyramidVertexPositionBuffer;
            var pyramidVertexColorBuffer;
            var cubeVertexPositionBuffer;
            var cubeVertexColorBuffer;
            var cubeVertexIndexBuffer;

            function initBuffers() {
                pyramidVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pyramidVertexPositionBuffer);
                var vertices = [
                    // Front face
                     0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
                    -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
                     1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

                    // Right face
                     0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
                     1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
                     1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

                    // Back face
                     0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
                     1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
                    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

                    // Left face
                     0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
                    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
                    -1.0, -1.0,  1.0
                ];
                gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
                pyramidVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
                pyramidVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = 12;

                pyramidVertexColorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pyramidVertexColorBuffer);
                var colors = [
                    // Front face
                    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,

                    // Right face
                    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
                    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,

                    // Back face
                    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,

                    // Left face
                    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
                    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0
                ];
                gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
                pyramidVertexColorBuffer.itemSize = 4;
                pyramidVertexColorBuffer.numItems = 12;


                cubeVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexPositionBuffer);
                vertices = [
                    // Front face
                    -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
                     1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
                     1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
                    -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,

                    // Back face
                    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
                    -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
                     1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
                     1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

                    // Top face
                    -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
                    -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
                     1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
                     1.0,  1.0, -1.0,

                    // Bottom face
                    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
                     1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
                     1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
                    -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

                    // Right face
                     1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
                     1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
                     1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
                     1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

                    // Left face
                    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
                    -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
                    -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
                    -1.0,  1.0, -1.0
                ];
                gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
                cubeVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
                cubeVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = 24;

                cubeVertexColorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexColorBuffer);
                colors = [
                    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], // Front face
                    [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0], // Back face
                    [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0], // Top face
                    [1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0], // Bottom face
                    [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], // Right face
                    [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]  // Left face
                ];
                var unpackedColors = [];
                for (var i in colors) {
                    var color = colors[i];
                    for (var j=0; j < 4; j++) {
                        unpackedColors = unpackedColors.concat(color);
                    }
                }
                gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(unpackedColors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
                cubeVertexColorBuffer.itemSize = 4;
                cubeVertexColorBuffer.numItems = 24;

                cubeVertexIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexIndexBuffer);
                var cubeVertexIndices = [
                    0, 1, 2,      0, 2, 3,    // Front face
                    4, 5, 6,      4, 6, 7,    // Back face
                    8, 9, 10,     8, 10, 11,  // Top face
                    12, 13, 14,   12, 14, 15, // Bottom face
                    16, 17, 18,   16, 18, 19, // Right face
                    20, 21, 22,   20, 22, 23  // Left face
                ];
                gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(cubeVertexIndices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
                cubeVertexIndexBuffer.itemSize = 1;
                cubeVertexIndexBuffer.numItems = 36;
            }


            var rPyramid = 0;
            var rCube = 0;

            function drawScene() {
              gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
              gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

              mat4.perspective(45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0, pMatrix);

              mat4.identity(mvMatrix);

              mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [-1.5, 0.0, -8.0]);



              mvPushMatrix();
              mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(rPyramid), [0, 1, 0]);

              gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pyramidVertexPositionBuffer);
              gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, pyramidVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

              gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pyramidVertexColorBuffer);
              gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute, pyramidVertexColorBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

              setMatrixUniforms();
              gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, pyramidVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);

              mvPopMatrix();


              makeCube(
                 {'r':0.3,'g':0.3,'b':0.87,'a':1.0},  // color
                 {'x':3.5,'y':1.0,'z':2.0},       // position
                 {'x':0.0,'y':0.0,'z':0.0},       // rotation
                 0.5                     // length
              );
               makeCube(
                 {'r':0.9,'g':0.7,'b':0.17,'a':1.0},  // color
                 {'x':3.5,'y':1.0,'z':2.0},       // position
                 {'x':0.0,'y':0.0,'z':0.0},       // rotation
                 0.5                     // length
              );
               makeCube(
                 {'r':0.3,'g':0.3,'b':0.87,'a':1.0},  // color
                 {'x':3.5,'y':1.0,'z':2.0},       // position
                 {'x':0.0,'y':0.0,'z':0.0},       // rotation
                 0.1                     // length
              );
               makeCube(
                 {'r':0.3,'g':0.5,'b':0.87,'a':1.0},  // color
                 {'x':0.5,'y':3.0,'z':12.0},       // position
                 {'x':0.0,'y':0.0,'z':0.0},       // rotation
                 0.8                     // length
              );
               makeCube(
                 {'r':0.5,'g':0.3,'b':0.87,'a':1.0},  // color
                 {'x':0.1,'y':-3.0,'z':5.0},       // position
                 {'x':0.0,'y':0.0,'z':0.0},       // rotation
                 0.4                     // length
              );
            }

           var oCubeColorBuffer = null;
           function _makeCubeColorBuffer(aColor){


               oCubeColorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, oCubeColorBuffer);
                var aColors = [
                    [aColor.r, aColor.g, aColor.b, aColor.a], // Front face
                    [aColor.r, aColor.g, aColor.b, aColor.a], // Back face
                    [aColor.r, aColor.g, aColor.b, aColor.a], // Top face
                    [aColor.r, aColor.g, aColor.b, aColor.a], // Bottom face
                    [aColor.r, aColor.g, aColor.b, aColor.a], // Right face
                    [aColor.r, aColor.g, aColor.b, aColor.a]  // Left face
                ];
                var unpackedColors = [];
                for (var i in aColors) {
                    var color = aColors[i];
                    for (var j=0; j < 4; j++) {
                        unpackedColors = unpackedColors.concat(color);
                    }
                }
                gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(unpackedColors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
                oCubeColorBuffer.itemSize = 4;
                oCubeColorBuffer.numItems = 24;        

              return oCubeColorBuffer;
           }

           var oCubePositionBuffer = null;    
           function _makeCubePositionBuffer(fLength){


              oCubePositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
              gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, oCubePositionBuffer);
              var aVertices = [
                 // Front face
                 -1.0*fLength, -1.0*fLength,  1.0*fLength,
                  1.0*fLength, -1.0*fLength,  1.0*fLength,
                  1.0*fLength,  1.0*fLength,  1.0*fLength,
                 -1.0*fLength,  1.0*fLength,  1.0*fLength,

                 // Back face
                 -1.0*fLength, -1.0*fLength, -1.0*fLength,
                 -1.0*fLength,  1.0*fLength, -1.0*fLength,
                  1.0*fLength,  1.0*fLength, -1.0*fLength,
                  1.0*fLength, -1.0*fLength, -1.0*fLength,

                 // Top face
                 -1.0*fLength,  1.0*fLength, -1.0*fLength,
                 -1.0*fLength,  1.0*fLength,  1.0*fLength,
                  1.0*fLength,  1.0*fLength,  1.0*fLength,
                  1.0*fLength,  1.0*fLength, -1.0*fLength,

                 // Bottom face
                 -1.0*fLength, -1.0*fLength, -1.0*fLength,
                  1.0*fLength, -1.0*fLength, -1.0*fLength,
                  1.0*fLength, -1.0*fLength,  1.0*fLength,
                 -1.0*fLength, -1.0*fLength,  1.0*fLength,

                 // Right face
                  1.0*fLength, -1.0*fLength, -1.0*fLength,
                  1.0*fLength,  1.0*fLength, -1.0*fLength,
                  1.0*fLength,  1.0*fLength,  1.0*fLength,
                  1.0*fLength, -1.0*fLength,  1.0*fLength,

                 // Left face
                 -1.0*fLength, -1.0*fLength, -1.0*fLength,
                 -1.0*fLength, -1.0*fLength,  1.0*fLength,
                 -1.0*fLength,  1.0*fLength,  1.0*fLength,
                 -1.0*fLength,  1.0*fLength, -1.0*fLength
              ];
              gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(aVertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
              oCubePositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
              oCubePositionBuffer.numItems = 24;

              return oCubePositionBuffer;
           }

          var oCubeIndexBuffer = null;   
           function _makeCubeVertexIndexBuffer(){

                oCubeIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, oCubeIndexBuffer);
                var cubeVertexIndices = [
                    0, 1, 2,      0, 2, 3,    // Front face
                    4, 5, 6,      4, 6, 7,    // Back face
                    8, 9, 10,     8, 10, 11,  // Top face
                    12, 13, 14,   12, 14, 15, // Bottom face
                    16, 17, 18,   16, 18, 19, // Right face
                    20, 21, 22,   20, 22, 23  // Left face
                ];
                gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(cubeVertexIndices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
                oCubeIndexBuffer.itemSize = 1;
                oCubeIndexBuffer.numItems = 36;      
              return oCubeIndexBuffer;
           }





           function makeCube(aColor, aPosition, aRotation, fLength){
                 mvPushMatrix();
                mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [aPosition.x, aPosition.y, aPosition.z]);

               // mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(rCube), [aRotation.x, aRotation.y, aRotation.z]);

                var oCubeVertexPositionBuffer = _makeCubePositionBuffer(fLength);
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, oCubeVertexPositionBuffer);
                gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, oCubeVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

                var oCubeVertexColorBuffer = _makeCubeColorBuffer(aColor);
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, oCubeVertexColorBuffer);
                gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute, oCubeVertexColorBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

                var oCubeVertexIndexBuffer = _makeCubeVertexIndexBuffer();
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, oCubeVertexIndexBuffer);
                setMatrixUniforms();
                gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, oCubeVertexIndexBuffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

                mvPopMatrix();

           }





            var lastTime = 0;

            function animate() {
                var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
                if (lastTime != 0) {
                    var elapsed = timeNow - lastTime;

                    rPyramid += (90 * elapsed) / 1000.0;
                    rCube -= (75 * elapsed) / 1000.0;
                }
                lastTime = timeNow;
            }


            function tick() {
                requestAnimFrame(tick);
                drawScene();
                animate();
            }


            function webGLStart() {
                var canvas = document.getElementById("lesson04-canvas");
                initGL(canvas);
                initShaders()
                initBuffers();

                gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

                tick();
            }

        </script> 


        </head> 


        <body onload="webGLStart();"> 
            <a href="http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=370">&lt;&lt; Back to Lesson 4</a><br /> 

            <canvas id="lesson04-canvas" style="border: none;" width="500" height="500"></canvas> 

            <br/> 
            <a href="http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=370">&lt;&lt; Back to Lesson 4</a><br /> 

            <!-- Google Analytics stuff, please ignore - nothing to do with WebGL :-) --> 
            <script type="text/javascript"> 
                var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
                document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
            </script> 
            <script type="text/javascript"> 
                try {
                    var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-2240015-5");
                    pageTracker._trackPageview();
                } catch(err) {
                }
            </script> 

        </body> 

        </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

They are all actually being drawn.  The first three are "on top of each other" meaning that they render as if they are one cube.  The last two are outside the viewing frustum of your viewport.  Try just the following calls to makeCube() and you will see two:

```
      makeCube(
         {'r':0.3,'g':0.3,'b':0.87,'a':1.0},  // color
         {'x':3.5,'y':1.0,'z':2.0},       // position
         {'x':0.0,'y':0.0,'z':0.0},       // rotation
         0.5                     // length
      );
      makeCube(
         {'r':0.3,'g':0.3,'b':0.87,'a':1.0},  // color
         {'x':1.5,'y':1.0,'z':2.0},       // position
         {'x':0.0,'y':0.0,'z':0.0},       // rotation
         0.5                     // length
      );
```